# UIImagePickerController.cameraViewTransform ignores translation

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, transform

My app stopped working correctly with iOS 4.3. It uses a custom camera view overlay for the UIImagePickerController. Because of the aspect ratio differences between camera and screen live view by default has a black bar at the bottom. To get rid of it I used to apply two transforms which shift the view down and scales it to full screen:

```
self.cameraFeed = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 25.0);
self.cameraFeed.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 480.0/430.0, 480.0/430.0);
```

With the current iOS version it seems that the translation transform doesn't do anything - I have a 25px black bar at the bottom and changing the values doesn't have any effect. However scale and rotate transforms work as expected.

Anyone has any similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the video preview layer (available since 4.2 if memory serves) instead of UIImagePicker. With it you can fully customize your UI as you see fit.